# Delete lines in CSV file with a column condition in bash

Tags: r, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a big CSV file (5Go). The header is:

```
run number,export,downerQ,coefUpQuality,chooseMode,demandF,nbPLots,standarDevPop,nbCitys,whatWord,priceMaxWineF,marketColor,[step],giniIndexReserve,giniIndexPatch,meanQualityTotal,meanQualityMountain,meanQualityPlain,DiffExtCentral,nbcentralPlots,meanPatchByNetwork,sum_q_viti_moutain,sum_q_viti_plaine
"3","false","0.5","0.01","false","7000","10","2","10","0","70","false","0","0","0.07083333333333335","0","0","0","0","0","0","48","0"
"4","false","0.5","0.01","false","7000","10","2","10","0","70","false","0","0","0.04285714285714286","0","0","0","0","0","0","42","0"
"2","false","0.5","0.01","false","7000","10","2","10","0","70","false","0","0","0.05348837209302328","0","0","0","0","0","0","43","0"
```

I would like keep only rows that contain "500" in the field [step] (the thirteenth field).

- I have tried to import this CSV in sqlite ... but deleting crash ...
- R also crash (even with fread from data.table)

Does someone have a solution with tools like `sed`, `awk` or any other command?

Comment: Check out [csvfix](https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/).  It can certainly do it.  In shell, a first step might be `grep -E '^run number|,"500",'` to select the title line and the lines that contain a 500 somewhere; you can then whittle it down to the 500's in column 13 with `awk`.  Or you can do the whole job in awk: `awk -F, 'NR == 1 || $13 == "\"500\"" { print }'` (untested, you might need to set `OFS` to `,` too, but probably don't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk seems the way to go:

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 || $13 == "\"500\""' filename
```

Where `NR == 1` is to preserve the first line (the header), and after that it's only lines of which the 13th field is `"500"`.

Comment: Tank you wintermute and Jonathan ... do not forget `-F,` for `--field-separator`